# getting an error on jslint while creating a new object using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, this, var

For some reason this code is giving a lint. I can't really figure out why. 
It says: 'was expecting a assignment or function call, and instead saw an expression.'
What does that mean?

```
window.onload = function (){ 

    function SuspectOne (naam, leeftijd, wie){
        this.naam = Spencer Hawes;
        this.leeftijd = 22;
        this.wie = zoon van de man;
    }

     function SuspectTwo (naam, leeftijd, wie){
        this.naam = Tyrone Biggums;
        this.leeftijd = 28;
        this.wie = lokale herionejunk;
    }

     function SuspectThree (naam, leeftijd, wie){
        this.naam = Ellie Campbell Hawes;
        this.leeftijd = 40;
        this.wie = vrouw van de man;
    }

    var verdachten = new Array[];
    verdachten[0] = new Verdachte("Spencer Hawes", 22, "zoon van de man");
    verdachten[1] = new Verdachte("Tyrone Biggums", 28, "lokale herionejunk");
    verdachten[2] = new Verdachte("Ellie Spencer Hawes", 40, "vrouw van de man");

    for(x=0; x<verdachten.length; x++){
        console.log("De verdachte is de  " + verdachten[x].leeftijd + "jaar oud " + verdachten[x].naam  + ", de " + verdachten[x].wie);
    }

};
```

Can someone help me with this? I would really like a lint free code.

Comment: Does your code actually work? I'm assuming this is only a part of it because we can't see `Verdachte`. Your `SuspectXYZ` definitions don't really make sense either, you're just ignoring the arguments. What linter are you using, a command line one, jslinst.com or jshint.com? They all throw over a dozen issues with the sample that you posted.

Comment: I used jsHint, but I'm using jsLint now too. There are indeed quitte a lot errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have strings not in quotes:

```
this.naam = Spencer Hawes;
```

should be

```
this.naam = 'Spencer Hawes';
```

also

```
this.wie = 'zoon van de man';
```

It also might give errors for the `new Array[]` stuff, you should probably use object literals:

```
var verdachten = [];
```

Also the linter should give line numbers so you can easily find what's wrong.

Comment: The error is gone now, but now there is an error on this, saying the same thing.    var verdachten = new Array[];
    verdachten[0] = new Verdachte['Spencer Hawes', 22, 'zoon van de man'];
    verdachten[1] = new Verdachte['Tyrone Biggums', 28, 'lokale herionejunk'];
    verdachten[2] = new Verdachte['Ellie Campbell Hawes', 40, 'vrouw van de man'];

Comment: `var verdachten = [];`  `verdachten[0] = ['Spencer Hawes',22,'zoon van de man'];`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the suspect functions (they aren't using the parameters?), but it doesn't seem like `Verdachte` exists. You may want to read about js objects/functions a bit